# SPRESENSEの録音機能でコーデックタイプをPCMとMP3を自在に切り替えたい

Tags: c, spresense, arduino

SPRESENSEでボタンを押下することで録音コーデックタイプをPCMとMP3に変換できるようにしたいです。
実際に実装してみると、
シリアルモニター上に

```
Attention: module[4][0] attention id[1]/code[6] (objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cpp L84)
```

と表示されます。検索してみても根本的な解決に至らずに困っております。
何かご存知の方がいらっしゃったら、ご教示いただきたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: コーデックタイプを切り替えたいということでしょうか。この情報だけだとよく分からないので、試しているコードを貼り付けるなど、もう少し具体的な質問の方が良いと思います。

Comment: @kzz さん　
コメントありがとうございます。データの吸い上げが間に合っていないようでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cpp L84は
spresense.gitの/sdk/modules/audio/objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cppだと思うので、以下のエラーになるようです。
AS_ATTENTION_SUB_SIMPLE_FIFO_OVERFLOW

ユーザーズガイドによると、バッファのオーバーフローだからデータの吸い上げが間に合っていないのではないでしょうか？
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_as_attention_sub_code_simple_fifo_overflow

Comment: データの吸い上げが間に合っていませんでした。サブコアに処理を移したらうまく回りました。回答ありがとうございました！